# Finding measurement of angles

Tags: geometry

I am not really sure if my answer is correct. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

The difference between the measures of an angle and its supplement is forty eight. Find the measure of both angles.

$$a+b=180\\
b-a=48$$

$2a=132$ divided by $2$ is $a=66$

$$66+b=180\\
b=180-66\\
b=114$$

My answers: $a=66$ and $b=114$

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You can check by arithmetic that the numbers you got are right.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: just check your answers

Answer (score 1):

@ user133921 :

Even is your result is apparently correct, your calculus is wrong : there is a mismatch with $a$ and $b$. You find $a=66$ and $b=114$. Hence $a-b=-48$ which doesn't agree with the given equation $a-b=48$. I suppose that you will find by yourself where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Let the measures of the angles be $a$ and $b$. Also, let $a$ be the larger angle ($a > b$)
$$a+b=180^\circ$$
$$a-b=48^\circ$$
Subtract the first equation from the second to get rid of $a$. This is called *elimination*.
$$2b=132^\circ$$
$$b=\dfrac{132^\circ}{2}$$
$$b=66^\circ$$
Plug the value of $b$ into either equation.
$$a+66^\circ=180^\circ$$
$$a=180^\circ-66^\circ$$
$$a=114^\circ$$
The angle measures are $114^\circ$ and $66^\circ$. So yes, you are correct.